# Padding only applies to me in 1 div, why?

Tags: html, css

I write the same padding for 2 different div elements and it only applies to 1 of them.

I already tried applying the style to different elements, using margin, creating more divs, using width and probably more things, but can't find the solution. Also, is this a correct way of doing it? Should I use buttons instead?

HTML

```
    <div class="login">
        <div class="button1"><p class="pButton"><a href="#">Login to see list</a></p></div>
        <div class="button2"><p class="pButton"><a href="#">Login to view profile</a></p></div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.login {
  text-align: center;
  margin-right:2px 20px;
}

.button1 {
  display: inline-block;
  padding:2px 10px;
}

.button2 {
  display: inline-block;
  padding:2px 10px;
}

.button1, .button2 a {
  background-color: #b0f4e6;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

both `div` tags have same `padding`, and I've just found something wrong in your code.

in your CSS code,

```
/* It means applying background-color at .button1 and .button2 > a */
.button1, .button2 a {
  background-color: #b0f4e6;
}
```

so, this codes would be like it

```
.button1, .button2{
  background-color: #b0f4e6;
}

/* OR */
.button1 a, .button2 a{
  background-color: #b0f4e6;
}
```

```css
.login {
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 2px 20px;
}

.button1 {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2px 10px;
}

.button2 {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2px 10px;
}

.button1,
.button2 {
  background-color: #b0f4e6;
}
```

```html
<div class="login">
  <div class="button1">
    <p class="pButton"><a href="#">Login to see list</a></p>
  </div>
  <div class="button2">
    <p class="pButton"><a href="#">Login to view profile</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try `[attribute^=value]` selector. in this case , will use `[class^="button"]`

Answer (score 0):

better u write ur code like this:

> HTML

```
    <div class="button1"><p class="pButton"><a href="#">Login to view List</a></p></div>
</div>
<div class="login">
    <div class="button2"><p class="pButton"><a href="#">Login to see Profile</a></p></div>
```

> CSS

```
.button1 , .button2 {

background-color: #b0f4e6;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.login {
  text-align: center;
}
.button1 ,.button2{
  display: inline-block;
}
.button1 a, .button2 a {
  background-color: #b0f4e6;
  padding:20px 10px;
  color:black;
}
```

```html
<div class="login">
        <div class="button1"><p class="pButton"><a href="#">Login to see list</a></p></div>
        <div class="button2"><p class="pButton"><a href="#">Login to view profile</a></p></div>
</div>
```

can u try this ? 
that's all...